# How to add together strings from an asynchronous callback?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, google-chrome-extension, callback

This extension calls the Goo.gl URL shortener and then tries to add together its reply into one string (for emailing purposes). However, since its asynchronous, the code moves on before adding together the shortened URL. How can I get it to add in the string before going on?

```
for(i;i<length;i++){
      getShortURL(tabs[i].url, function(short_url) { 
      string += encodeURL(short_url); 
      });
    }
//do something with string... 

//
function getShortURL(long_url, callback ){
...
}
```

Comment: Update: In the end, I found the simplest solution was to make the XMLHttpRequest synchronous so that everything is returned in order and can easily be combined into one string.

Answer (score 3):

You could continue your actions inside the `callback` after the url string has returned.

```
for(i;i<length;i++){
      getShortURL(tabs[i].url, function(short_url) { 
      string += encodeURL(short_url); 
      //do something with string... 
      });
    }

//
function getShortURL(long_url, callback ){
...
}
```

if the code need to run after all the urls have returned use a condition checking that this is your last code.

This might work for you:

```
for(var i=0,x=0;i<length;i++){
      getShortURL(tabs[i].url, function(short_url) { 
          string += encodeURL(short_url); 
          x++;
          if (x === length) {
              //do something with string... 
          }
      });
    }

//
function getShortURL(long_url, callback ){
...
}
```

Comment: Could, and in fact, must. :-)

Comment: But it's in a for loop and needs to go through multiple elements before using the string.

Comment: Look at what I just added. I believe this is the solution in your case.

Comment: @iMoses: Doesn't handle the situation where multiple AJAX calls might come back out-of-order.

Comment: Matt, yes it does. Notice that `x` is incremented inside the callback, making the condition `true` only after the function has been called `length` times. The urls may not be in order (no one said it had to) but they will all be there.

Comment: @iMoses: Yes, I did notice that, that wasn't what I was talking about. I was talking specifically about the URLs being out-of-order.

Comment: Ok, make sense. No one said it was suppose to be in order :) If so the script do need to be changed, of course.

Answer (score 1):

You actually have two problems. One is that your asynchronous method returns immediately, the second is that since your calls are asynchronous, there is no guarantee that they'll return in the same order you sent them out.

You could do something like this:

```
var strings = [];
for(i;i<length;i++){
      getShortURL(tabs[i].url, function(short_url) { 
          string[i] = encodeURL(short_url);
      });
}

// wait until the array is filled (use setTimeout) and then construct the final string from the array.
```